# Leaking Door Newly Installed By Pro

Tags: doors, carpentry, door-frame

We just got a new door installed by a professional and there seems to be a bunch of leaks in the door. I am not sure if this is normal or not on a new door install and if they are easy to fix myself or they are not a big deal.

Most of the air leaks seem to be coming from here
[image]

Leaks in corners and sides, I see it in 3 spots, but just posted on picture[image] (I can see light come through)

[image: Interior]

[image: Interior Frame]

[image: Exterior Frame]

[image: Exterrior]

Comment: You said you *got* this door installed? Was this by a friend or a professional? This is mainly to cover the "is this normal" part of your question.

Comment: By a professional

Comment: I'd say it's pretty normal for a first DIY door install by a home owner, but certainly not for a professional. Being concerned about it is determined by your tolerance for cold air and rain entering your house. I'd get your pro back to do a better job.

Comment: In addition to all the problems already discussed, the lock is definitely not as straight as I would expect for a professional installation.

Comment: Speaking of the lock... I think its kinda funny how someone went  out of their way to install a number lock on a door that probably gives when you lean on to it....

Comment: I bought a box strike plate and tried to get him into install it when he replaced the door, but evidently that was not possible for reasons I don't understand. I will say that whenever I have done stuff myself on doors in the past I have found it challenging (replacing lock + strike plate, replacing mortis lock), but that is why I hired a pro.

https://www.amazon.com/Battalion-3EJD3-Strike-Plate-Chrome/dp/B004KF6SV6/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=box+strike+plate&qid=1606945171&sr=8-3

Comment: @jdeyrup it was possible to cut out like an inch of material on the right side, so I dont think any reasonable deadbolt would have been an issue for a professional.

Answer (score 2):

Your second image is a pretty good indicator that this is not normal. You can see rubber insulation at the end of the door. This insulation serves no purpose if it is not compressed against another surface. Light shining through is only a symptom of the problem. The fact that the right (image angle) side of your wall has an extrusion is of course a bit complicated, but simply cutting it out of the door (with a very generous offset) is definitely not the right way to approach this, especially since it is part of the frame which is static and does not need to move.

Thus answering your question if this is normal: Other countries might have different standards, but in my country I would absolutely not accept this kind of work. When I order a door I expect it to be perfectly sealed unless I tell them otherwise.

For your other question if you are able to fix this. It is hard to tell from the image, but the door seems to be at least level, so the offset between the door and its frame on the closing side seems to be constant. The simplest solution would be to remove the rubber insulation and replace it with a larger diameter rubber insulation. Since the pretty large gap on the (image angle) right part of the door does not need to move at all any kind of fixed insulation method (i.e. spraying some foam and cutting it and then paint over it) should probably do the trick.

**edit**: based on your 5th image, why is the gap on the right side a leak issue? From the outside it seems that the frame is properly sealed against the rest of the house. It looks horrible from the inside but leakage should not happen there.

**edit2**: This is also not very reasurring (huge gap and not even remotely level)
[image]

Comment: You are stating that shoddy work  is the norm in the US. While it may not be uncommon, it certainly is not normal. Bad human behavior knows no geopolitical boundary's.

Comment: I started to be a bit careful with general statements, I've learned just because my government says its better does not mean it is objectively better.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a fair test but when I hold a candle near the holes I hear a puff and the candle flickers. I am not sure why the hole is leaking though; maybe it indicates another problem.

Comment: This is SUBSTANDARD work in the USA for sure!  It was not done by a "professional" but rather a poser claiming to be professional.

Comment: @jdeyrup If you are saying that air is blowing out your candle if held next to the hole from the extrusion in your wall that means not even the insulation here is done right: https://i.imgur.com/LYgNYW5.png

Comment: @jwh20 - Perhaps you mean to say, In the USA, this would be coincided substandard.   No location was provided by the OP. It makes no difference where it is.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I did rephrase it, I realized it insinuated some general quality issues in the US, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: It might be acceptable in some 3rd World location where even having a door is a luxury.

Comment: @jwh20 I actually spend quite some time a year in a so called "3rd world country". It is actually less about quality work being a luxury and more about it just not being required. I am facing 35+°C summers, yet my house in Switzerland (definitely 1st world) has no AC. I had to be creative to set up my own thing that didnt require a building permit. They would laugh at it, however I laugh at their houses not properly sealing anything since what feels like 150% humidity causes everything to "move around". Then again I dont really see what a properly sealed house would accomplish there.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, that its all a matter of priorities and perspective and less of capabilities :)

Comment: @jwh20 a pro is simply someone who charges money for work, skill not required.